# C++ std::string::assign works strange

Tags: c++, string

need some help from experienced engineers. I've wrote a function, which gets a string and takes a substring from it. Substrings separated from each other with comma ','. I use assign() function to copy substrings. My code:

```
void my_function(string devices)
{
    unsigned int last=0;
    unsigned int address;
    printf("whole string: %s\n",devices.c_str());

    for (unsigned int z=0; z<devices.size();z++)
    {
        if(devices[z]==',')     
        {
            zone_name.assign(devices,last,z);
            printf("device:%s\n",zone_name.c_str());
            address=get_kd_address_by_name(zone_name);
            last=z+1;
            if(address>0)
            {   
                //doing stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem: only first iteration works.
In terminal i get:

```
whole string: device1,device2,device3,000001029ADA
device:device1
device:device2,device3
device:device3,000001029ADA
```

Why assign() takes characters after ','?

Comment: 1st hint: remove TAB characters (replace by for spaces) from verbatim copied code.

Comment: "zone_name" is not declared....please post code that at least compiles...

Comment: I know that isnt your question but, if you want to know different ways to split a string in tokens or like to see different solutions, check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::string::assign` (the overload you are using) takes a position and a length. Not two positions. `z` is a position in the `devices` string. It only works for the first string since in that case, your starting position is 0, so the length and the ending position are  the same.

```
unsigned int length = z - last;
zone.assign(devices, last, length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to split the string based on some delimiter, why not used `boost::split`?

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    std::string input("foo,bar,baz");
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    std::cout << "Original: " << input << std::endl;      
    boost::split( output, input, boost::is_any_of(std::string(",")) );
    for( size_t i=0; i<output.size(); ++i )
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << output[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Original: foo,bar,baz
0: foo
1: bar
2: baz
```